# Why does the Amazon .Net SDK not see any job flows?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

My company has grown weary of constantly using the AWS console to setup our map reduce clusters and needs more configurability than the console provides. I'm using the .Net AWS SDK to write a simple application that allows us to create and control job flows. Unfortunately, my calls to `DescribeJobFlows` are always returning empty (despite the fact that I can see jobs in the AWS Console). Here's some sample code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var amazonClient = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient( "<redacted>", "<redacted>" );
    var response = amazonClient.DescribeJobFlows( new DescribeJobFlowsRequest() );
    Console.WriteLine( response.DescribeJobFlowsResult.JobFlows.Count );
}
```

This simple program always prints 0.

I've triple-checked that my aws access key and secret keys are correct, and that I have job flows running under that account. I created several running job flows today, so at least those should be included in the results. I don't see any filtering by region or anything that might have funny defaults in the request.

Why can't I see my job flows?

Answer (score 1):

After writing that and being really confused for a while, I found the `ServiceURL` property on `AmazonElasticMapReduceConfig`. Once I [looked up the endpoint](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) for my region and set the appropriate value, I was able to get the results I expected.